# Date Format prevent Change

Tags: excel, calendar, formatting, cell, vba

I hope you are well. I have a small issue happening with an excel sheet. People tend to but the date in a cell in any format they wish which is causing problems when we try to load into a separate database. 
What i would like to do is not give them the opportunities to chose put have a method where by they can only chose a certain date format for that cell. Like a calendar or date selection will pop up once the cell is clicked. 
I have attached a picture of the issue i am having and trying to prevent. 
[image] 
Any help you can give is as always greatly appreciated

Comment: How is `14/7/2016` a `mm/dd/yyyy` date format?

Comment: @Philip Connell have you looked at my answer below ? with an alternative solution

Comment: HI Shai. Thank you so much for your help. I have entered the code and it compiles with no problem but nothing is happening with the dates in the data column. The date field is in column P would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach,  let them put whatever date format they want (as long as it's recognized as a date), and then convert it to your desired format.
See code below:

```
Public Sub Change_DateFormat()

Dim rng1    As Range

' modify to your desired column where you store your dates
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
rng1.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

End Sub
```